# STM32 ADC: leave it running at 'high' speed or switch it off as much as possible?

Tags: stm32, adc

I am using a G0 with one ADC and 8 channels. Works fine. I use 4 channels. One is temperature that is measured constantly and I am interested in the value every 60s. Another one is almost the opposite: it is measuring sound waves for a couple a minutes per day and I need those samples at 10kHz.

I solved this by letting all 4 channels sample at 10kHz and have the four readings moved to memory by DMA (array of length 4 with 1 measurement each). Every 60s I take the temperature and when I need the audio, I retrieve the audio values.

If I had two ADC's, I would start the temperature ADC reading for 1 conversion every 60s. Non-stop. And I would only start the audio ADC for the the couple of minutes a day that it is needed. But with the one ADC solution, it seems simple to let all conversions run at this high speed continuously and that raised my question: Is there any true downside in having 40.000 conversions per second, 24 hours per day? If not, the code is simple. I just have the most recent values in memory all the time. But maybe I ruin the chip? I use too much energy I know. But there is plenty of it in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't going to "wear it out" by running it when you don't need to.

The main problems are wasting power and RAM.

If you have enough of these, then the lesser problems are:

The wasted power will become heat, this may upset your temperature measurements (this is a very small amount though).

Having the DMA running will increase your interrupt latency and maybe also slow down the processor slightly, if it encounters bus contention (this only matters if you are close to capacity in these regards).

Having it running all the time may also have the advantage of more stable readings, not being perturbed turning things on and off.

Comment: Sounds quite positive then. Will try do do an experiment to see if high DMA traffic has effect on latency. Had never thought about that. Really always assumed DMA comes for “free”. Happy I asked